# How to enable SQL Server Agent job execution from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-agent-job

I have an agent job that executes a `.dtsx` package. It needs to be called from a stored procedure owned by a database user, and used by the app and executes as owner.

Granted

Code:

```
DECLARE @return_value INT

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[rscc_drop_off_caller]

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

I gave the user `SQLAgentUserRole` and confirmed it has execute on `sp_start_job`.

If I run:

```
DECLARE @ReturnCode INT;

EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_start_job N'RSCC Push CCD To AIM';

PRINT @ReturnCode;
```

from a window in SSMS, it runs fine.

But if I run:

```
exec csisql.rscc_drop_off_caller;
```

it fails with an error:

> Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Procedure sp_start_job, Line 1
>   The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_start_job', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'.
>
> The 'rscc_drop_off_caller' procedure attempted to return a status of NULL, which is not allowed. A status of 0 will be returned instead.

I even tried to drop and recreate the stored procedure after granting the permission but I get the same error. The stored procedure is pretty simple:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[rscc_drop_off_caller]
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
DECLARE @ReturnCode int;

BEGIN
    EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_start_job N'RSCC Push CCD To AIM';
    RETURN (@ReturnCode); 
END
```

Sorry if I provided too much information. I really need to get this working but I'm stumped. Any help would be REALLY appreciated. Thanks in advance.

KT

To summarize: I need to be able to call the agent job from within the stored procedure. That currently fails although calling the job directly (exec...) as the owning user works fine.

Comment: Somewhere in the results ought to be a line saying something like "Executing as {SomeUserName}".   What does that say, and what permissions did that user have when you got the permissions error?

Comment: In what database did you create your procedure, in msdb or in user database?

Comment: @sepucic the stored procedure is in the csisql database which is a user database.

Comment: @Tab Alleman I assume you mean in the store procedure?  The stored prcedure is owned by dbo user but I have modified the procedure to execute as 'DAimConnUser' (the same user I granted permission to exec sp_start_job).  I have also tried to modify the procedure to execute as CALLER.  Neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.  I resolved the issue.  I modified the SP to execute as caller and granted specific permission to that DAimConnUser to execute the stored procedure.